# SSRS Report Builder not detecting all parameters

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report with **StartDate** and **EndDate** date parameters but when I pass it through the report builder, it doesn't seem to **map** the **EndDate** param. **I know this is because of the IF block** at the beginning however I've used this in a previous report without issue.[As you can see from this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZPOH.png), although this is not the exact query this has the same issue.

Is there a way around this, or **is there a way to update the parameter within an expression to get around the IF block?**

Comment: Not sure why somebody voted to close this question...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have SET the end date.
If you want the report to use both the parameter, you need to unset it.

But if all you are looking for is to check if they are the same and set the end date parameter, then you need to do that in the where clause

```
Select *

from your table

Where you_column between @start_date and case when @end_date = @start_date then dateadd(day,1,@start_date) else @end_date end
```